# Помогите разобратся с кодом

Tags: c

Подскажите, почему второй printf печатает "0 servers"?
http://pastebin.com/k1Tx2y45
Первый печатает то что я и ожидаю "99999"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int addr;
} sl_server_t;

typedef struct {
    sl_server_t *servers;
    size_t count;
    size_t allocated_len;
} server_list_t;

server_list_t server_list;

void ServerList_Init(size_t count) {
    if (count < 1) count = 1;
    server_list.servers = malloc(count * sizeof(*server_list.servers));
    if (!server_list.servers) {
        perror("realloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    server_list.allocated_len = count * sizeof(*server_list.servers);
    server_list.count = 0;
}

void ServerList_Add(sl_server_t server) {
    for (register size_t i = 0; i < server_list.count; i++) {
        if (server_list.servers[i].addr == server.addr)
            return;
    }

    if (server_list.count > server_list.allocated_len / sizeof(*server_list.servers)) {
        server_list.servers = realloc(server_list.servers, server_list.count * sizeof(*server_list.servers) * 2);
        if (!server_list.servers) {
            perror("realloc");
            exit(1);
        }
        server_list.allocated_len = server_list.count * sizeof(*server_list.servers) * 2;
    }

    server_list.servers[server_list.count] = server;
    server_list.count++;
}

void ServerList_Remove(sl_server_t server) {
    for (register size_t i = 0; i < server_list.count; i++) {
        if (server_list.servers[i].addr == server.addr) {
            server_list.servers[i] = server_list.servers[server_list.count - 1];
            memset(&server_list.servers[server_list.count - 1], 0, sizeof(sl_server_t));
            server_list.count--;
        }
    }
}

sl_server_t* ServerList_GetListPtr() {
    return server_list.servers;
}

int main() {
    ServerList_Init(2);

    sl_server_t srv;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
        srv.addr = i;
        ServerList_Add(srv);
    }

    sl_server_t *servers = ServerList_GetListPtr();
    size_t count = 0;
    while (servers->addr) {
        servers++;
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
        srv.addr = i;
        ServerList_Remove(srv);
    }

    for (size_t i = 10000; i < 100000; i++) {
        srv.addr = i;
        ServerList_Add(srv);
    }

    for (size_t i = 10000; i < 100000; i++) {
        srv.addr = i;
        ServerList_Remove(srv);
    }

    servers = ServerList_GetListPtr();
    count = 0;
    while (servers->addr) {
        servers++;
        count++;
    }
    printf("ok: %d servers", count);
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код в тело вопроса.

Comment: Сначала вставляете 99999 адресов, потом их же удаляете.

Comment: Ну протестировать новоиспеченный код же надо.

Comment: Знаете, в программировании есть такие понятия -- один, два, много.  Так и тестируйте по порядку.  Добавьте 1 адрес, распечатайте. Потом ... (все расписывать?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изначально вы выделяете место для 2 элементов, так? А при вашей логике когда пойдет выделение новой памяти? когда `count` станет равным 3, т.е. когда **уже** будут записаны элементы 0, 1 и 2 (ну, с `addr` 1, 2 и 3). Т.е. вы вылетаете за границу массива.

Дальше даже не рассматривал...

Comment: Увидел, сменил `if (server_list.count > server_list.allocated_len / sizeof(*server_list.servers))`  на `if (server_list.count >= server_list.allocated_len / sizeof(*server_list.servers))`, но все ровно ноль серверов пишет, где-то ещё что-то или я не так исправил?

Comment: @Виталий А что вы ожидаете? Вы потом удаляете первые 10000, потом пытаетесь повторно добавлять уже имеющиеся (они не добавятся), потом удаляете остальные. Вроде как раз все верно... Что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Да, работать с динамической памятью я не очень умею. Я хочу сделать список серверов неограниченого размера в который можно добавлять сервера, удалять по адресу(int для теста, надо будет по ip потом) и получить список всех серверов.

Comment: @Виталий Ну так вроде работает же. Я спрашивал - что вы ждете от второго вывода, что именно по-вашему должно быть выведено? И - насколько критично именно C, С++ не хотите? там масса готовых решений, просто ваш вариант не самый быстрый получается - с проверкой наличия записи в коллекции...

Comment: А-а, я пересмотрел и понял что ноль и должно быть, вообще я ожидал значения больше нуля, я не задумываясь вставил добавление произвольного кол. серверов и потом удаленое какого-то кол. для теста но случайно добавил столько же сколько удалил. Есть уже реализация на python, захотелось вот на C переписать для практики, а то вроде и знаю его нормально но практики мало, да и люблю я C, а C++ не люблю, его идеология не для меня, сам язык не плох для меня но то как на нем пишут мне не нравиться.

Comment: Да, это не самый оптимальный вариант, но серверов не много, поэтому не критично совсем. Хотя улучшить бы не против но не знаю как можно получше.

Comment: @Виталий Просто вы по сути имитируете `vector` из C++, а в этом случае лучше имитировать `hash_set` или по крайней мере просто `set`. первое - хэш-таблица, второе - бинарное (красно-черное) дерево. Просто у вас оказывается очень длинная операция вставки из-за прохода по всему списку для проверки, нет ли дубля. Что до C++ - ну, в конце-концов, его можно использовать и как "улучшенный C", http://ideone.com/v0zPbH - как видите, ничего особо страшного, но сравните скорость...